# VBA - File copy inherits read-only mode

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access application that uses VBA for a number of things.  I need to add a row to an excel spreadsheet before auto-importing the data - trust me there is no better way in this case.  Right now, this works as long as the spreadsheet isn't open by someone. However, if it is, I can't modify the spreadsheet and I get the pop-up of the spreadsheet in read-only mode.  To get around this, I added code to copy the existing spreadsheet to a temp folder and set the "Read-only" value to normal.  This SHOULD work - I think.  However, even when I try this, I still get the read-only error.  YET, when I check the value of my TEMP file, it's not set to read-only!!!

I'm guessing that read-only is really "locked by another user."

How can I accomplish my goal of getting access to edit that file / a temp copy?

Below is the code where I get the message:

```
Dim fso as Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call fso.CopyFile(myOriginalFolderFile, myTempFolderFile)
' copyfile works successfully
SetAttr myTempFolderFile, vbNormal
' still no error

Dim my_xl_app as Object
Dim my_xl_worksbook as Object
Set my_xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set my_xl_workbook = my_xl_app.Worksbooks.Open(myTempFolderFile)
' this is where it throws the message
```

Comment: You could open the read-only file in Excel, make the modifications, then `SaveAs` to the temp folder...

Comment: (Don't mind that the linked duplicate question is about .mdb, the problem is the same)

Comment: Well, I figured it out.  In the Save dialog box, there is a TINY option for "Tools" and "General Options" and it has a checkbox next to ‘Read-only recommended’. I've been programming for over 20 years and first time I even had this problem. lol

Answer (score 0):

In the Save dialog box, there is a TINY option for "Tools" and "General Options" and it has a checkbox next to ‘Read-only recommended’.